# Pull shopify image files

Tags: reactjs, shopify, store

I have been banging my head against the wall trying to work out how to use graphQL, to pull the images and then place them on the customer website. I am using the framework Hydrogen which is built for shopify. Now I have tried a few things. I have tried and use a package to fix my option, but the problem I am having is grabbing the images. I really dont want to make a sepreate database. I am happy with the shopify, but as stated at the start. I have no clue how to get them image files.

As said at the top I have tried using the GraphQL but cant pull from the database of shopify

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You get the files using files GraphQL query:

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2023-01/queries/files

and if you wish to upload them to Shopify you would use the fileCreate mutation:

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2023-01/mutations/fileCreate